# Passing cookie from controller to view in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, cookies

I have problem with getting cookie which I saved earlier. I want to pass it through controller to view. Here is my cookie saved in jQuery (it works, checked).

```
$('.wybierz').on('click',function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('name');

    Cookies.set('chosenComp', id);

    highlightChoice(id);
});
```

and here is my controller

```
public function index(Request $request){
    $cookie = Cookie::get('chosenComp');
    $actualComp = $cookie;
    $coms = DB::table('items')->get();
    $teams = DB::table('results')->get();
    return view('nowa_druzyna',['teams'=>$teams],['coms'=>$coms])->with('actualComp',$actualComp);
}
```

First of all I just wanted to try passing the cookie which is a number but it doesn't show. My view

```
<option selected class="showCurrentComp" id="">{{$actualComp}}</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript stores raw cookies, Laravel expects cookies to be encrypted, you can exempt your cookie from that in [the EncryptCookies middleware](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php)